# Is it possible to automatically install software when a user logs in through Group Policy?

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-server-2003, group-policy

I am trying to distribute software through group policy, I am able to get this working so that the users can go into Add/Remove Programs and select Install from network and then install the software. However, I would like the install to kick off as soon as the user logs in, is this possible?

I am using Windows Server 2003 and the client machines are running Windows 7.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Ali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102

The above link will talk you through assigning software to a user.  You can force software to install for a computer or user by using a group policy object.

You will need to first place your MSI within a folder which everyone can read and then assign it to a user via GPO.

To do this, creae a new group policy object and link it to the OU which contains your users.

Edit the group policy and go to `User Configuration` > `Software Settings` > `Software Installation` > Right Click > `New` > `Package`.

Select your MSI and then select `Assigned` as the deployment method.

[This page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783635%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) will talk you through the difference between publishing (making available) and assigning (forcing) software installations for users.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would also add that in the properties of the package in the Deployment tab under deployment options you need to make sure that 'Install this application at logon' is ticked, this done the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click your package in the group policy editor and check **Assign**.